# Mysql query not assigning/returning variables?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my Function/Class

```
class user
{
    public function get_data($username)
    {
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * WHERE user_name = ?"); //display oldest to newest
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

Here's how I do my Call.

```
$users = new user;
$user = $users->get_data($_POST['username']);
$_SESSION['username'] = $user['user_name'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $user['user_id'];
$_SESSION['credits'] = $user['user_credits'];
```

Here's my HTML

```
<li class="right"><a href="#">Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.</a></li>
<li class="right"><?php echo $_SESSION['credits']; ?></li>
<li class="right"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?></li>
```

So for some reason, only the `$_SESSION['username'];` print's out in the html, the credit/id doesn't have a value so it doesn't display anything, is my query right? I think it should work if the username is being displayed.

Comment: Shouldn't you first bind value and then execute?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out everyone, but it still doesn't give me the values when I run the script, it just gives me the username.

Comment: Because your query is wrong, see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute` before `bindValue`?

```
    $query->execute();
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
```

Should be

```
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $query->execute();
```

**Also**, Your Query is wrong

```
"SELECT * WHERE user_name = ?"   // SELECT from where?
```

Should be something like

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE user_name = ?"
```

Comment: I forgot the FROM, I didn't even see that! Thank you so much for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Execute function should be call after bind value

```
$query->execute();
$query->bindValue(1, $username);
```